# echoing a command to an output file from within a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

```
echo ((goto) 2>nul & cd "%~dp0\.." && rmdir /s /q "%~dp0") >> delete.bat
```

I'm using a batch file to create another separate batchfile by running this command. However, the line above doesn't appear at all in the "delete.bat" file. I'm sure it's an issue with the syntax, but I'm unable to see what the issue is exactly. Anyone got a clue?

Comment: The double ampersand has to be escaped.

Comment: I question why you need to do this. Why can't you write a script file and just call that with the appropriate parameters?  If it's a clean-up script then write a data file for it to read. Lower complexity is always good.

Comment: ...as well as the caret escaped ampersands, all percent characters  require doubling up too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> echo test ^&^& test
test && test
> echo test && testing
test
'testing' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Cmd.exe is interpreting your `echo` line as two commands due to the `&&`. You need to escape them with the `^` hat to get them emitted into the script.

See [Quoting and escaping](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping).

Comment: Nice! This solves the initial issue but another presents itself. How would I escape the variables so that the subsequent batch file has `%~dp0` in it instead?

Comment: LOL! Try `%%~dp0`.  See [Quoting and escaping](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting#Quoting_and_escaping)

Comment: dope, this fixed it!